# Sqlite incremental data backup in React Native

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, react-native, google-drive-api

I m using sqlite as database for my offline first React Native project and I am looking for a solution to backup this database and to upload to Google drive. 
But I didn't get the solution so far. If someone has done this or know how to please help me to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do the sqlite bindings you're using provide the standard [online backup api](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html)?

Comment: To achieve this try uploading your database files to Drive through Google Drive's API. [Here is an example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple) on how to upload files to drive and [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) you can find the refereence to the method create. If you want to upload many files simultaneously you might want to take a look at [batching upload requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch). Let me know if this was of any help and if you managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

I am using [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) for managing file system in my app.

Install the package and make sure it is linke either **autolinked** or **manually linked**

Run for android or iOS both

Import it using:

`import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';`

Now use this code to create the backup file of the database into your app file system.

```
RNFS.readFileAssets("newmydb.db", "base64")
.then(value => RNFS
    .getAllExternalFilesDirs()
    .then(path => RNFS.writeFile(path + "/" + 'database_backup.db', value, "base64"))
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Successful");
        alert('Backup created successfully!')
})
)
```